# ios/xcode/objective-c: Segue to modal view controller embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I have a segue from a button in a detail view controller to a new modal view controller that displays a map.

To pass the location to display on the map, I use preparetosegue as follows:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMap"]) {

        IDMapView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;   
            destViewController.contact=_contact;
             }
```

However, I after embedding the modal view controller in a navigation controller to implement a cancel button, the app is now crashing when I click on the button giving the error in the log:

```
[UINavigationController setContact:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8738ea5ce0
(lldb)
```

The error seems to have something to do with the navigation controller not having the property contact (which is on the view controller.)

Can anyone suggest the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `destinationViewController` is now a `UINavigationController` and not an `IDMapView`. You need to get the `topViewController` from the `UINavigationController`.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMap"]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    IDMapView *destViewController = navigationController.topViewController;   
    destViewController.contact=_contact;
}
```

Comment: Worked.  Awesome.  Thanks.